# Shared User ID and Signing with Android

Tags: android

I am trying to have 2 Android applications which can access each other's data.  I have a two test applications which I am experimenting with. I set the 'Shared user id' for each to `'com.gabysoft.sharedfiles'`. However, when I sign the first app and try and install it, I get the error:

```
11-05 16:50:33.422: ERROR/PackageManager(61): Package com.gabysoft.sharedfiles1 has no 
signatures that match those in shared user com.gabysoft.sharedfiles; ignoring!
```

Clearly, I am not signing it correctly (I am using Eclipse's "Export signed application package" function).  How do I properly sign the .apk file so that I don't have this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

If you set a sharedUserId, and install the app onto your device from Eclipse (which, by default during development, signs it with the debug key), you create a permanent bond between that signing key and sharedUserId. `/data/system/packages.xml`, as well as the Dalvik cache, hold info on shared user id's associated with apps. I, however, have not found a way to consistently wipe that old debug release leftovers on my GN, even after following the related thread on [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1219029).

So, if you really need to use the sharedUserId, you could append any fixed string to the sharedUserId just to change it in the AnroidManifest.xml only when developing and using the debug key. You should, however, have a check that you never check it into the code repository or release it, because once you set the sharedUserId and release the app, it's done. You must never change it, otherwise your app will loose access to its own files and will become unusable.

Watch out, sharedUserId is tricky. See this [blog post](http://java-hamster.blogspot.com/2010/05/androids-shareduserid.html) for possible related issues.

EDIT: I just noticed how old this question is, but I still think someone may find the answer valuable, as I have reached that question myself while Googling.

Comment: I believe that you are correct about installing using the debug key being the root of the problem, however, I believe that it is only a problem with earlier versions of Android (<= ~2.1?).  I have one phone running 2.1 and if I install using the debug key, then in order to switch to a real key I have to factory reset the phone (uninstalling the app does not work).  This is true on emulators running 2.1 as well.  However with more recent versions of Android, I do not experience this issue.

Comment: John, I'm running Android 4.1 on a Galaxy Nexus, and sadly I am not able to clean up the debug signed app with $ adb uninstall <package> nor cleaning up /data/system/packages.xml and clearing Dalvik cache :(

Comment: I don't have a 4.1 device ATM (and I have pretty much given up trying to use the emulator for anything), but I do have some 4.0.x and 3.x devices as well as several 2.x devices.  I have never experienced this problem on a version of Android 2.2.x or higher.  I can tell you, however, that on the devices that it does happen on, the only way I was able to ever get it to work again was to factory reset the device.

Answer (score 5):

I think both apps will have to be signed with the same key. Is it possible that you've just signed one app with your release key and the other app is already residing on the the phone or emulator but signed with a different (the debug?) key?

If so try uninstalling app 1, resign it with the same key as app 2, then install them both.

Or maybe there is another app that contains the same package name but has no shareduserid at all - it might be worth trying to uninstall that. Perhaps the first app with a shareduserid that gets installed with a particular package name goes in OK and thereafter anything containing that package and shareduserid  has to match the key that the first was signed with.

Comment: "Or maybe there is another app that contains the same package name but has no shareduserid at all - it might be worth trying to uninstall that." -- I like this theory.

Comment: I have tried uninstalling both applications, and when I try and install the first application (with the second currently NOT present) I get the error.  Is there something I need to do on the emulator to clear out the cert information that was present when they were originally installed? Thanks.

Comment: As an update, I created a new clean emulator, and I am able to get both apps to install, and they seem to be able to read each other's data.  However, on the first emulator, I still cannot install either one, even if I delete all of the app first.  Any idea why that is?

Comment: My only thought regarding the first emulator problem is to ask whether there might be a service you wrote that's installed and uses that package name?

Comment: To test the theory in my previous comment you could temporarily refactor the package name on both apps to something like 'com.gabysoft.sharedfilestemp' and see how that works out.

Comment: I have written no services.  However I had installed the apps unsigned (although I believe that Eclipse adds some default signing) and they were able to read each other's data.  I then deleted the apps and signed them properly, and was no longer able to install.  However, after I created a new emulator, I have not had any problems, even when I repeated the sequence I just described, but the first emulator seems to be permanently bugged.  Since I have it working with the new emulator, I guess, I am not as concerned.  Hopefully I will not have a problem when I move to real hardware.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

just set name android:sharedUserId like this pattern
xxx.yyy.zzz (dotted)

Comment: This is correct, it has to follow that pattern. One dot is sufficient, though.

Answer (score 0):

maybe its because you compiled both versions with same keystore.. just a guess tho